# VBA Loop. I don't understand the purpose of loops

Tags: vba

So I have a solution here to this:

Create a function (using For Next) that calculates the amount earned from depositing a lump sum in a bank account for n years.  In the workbook provided, €1,000  earns €276 after 5 years at 5%.  Test your function in cell E5.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function calprofit(investment As Single, years As Integer, rate As Single) As Single
Dim i As Integer

Dim amount As Single

amount = investment

For i = 1 To years
amount = amount * (1 + rate)
Next i

calprofit = amount - investment

End Function
```

I don't really understand what is happening here. Especially the part where it says

```
for i = 1 to years
```

and

```
amount = amount * (1 + rate)
```

Thanks for help and patience.

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through it in the debugger and watching what happens.

Comment: It's compounding the interest over each year.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop performs the code within the loop again and again for the duration of the loop, where the variable `i` in this case changes from 1 to the amount of years and every number in between.

In that loop, the amount is multiplied by the 1 + the rate. Suppose the rate is 5%, than 5% of the amount is added every time in the loop.

But I don't understand why you want to use a custom function for this. There are a lot of financial formulas in Excel to calculate these sort of things and you can just use an Excel formula for this: `calprofit = investment*(1+rate)^years - investment`

Comment: what you mean every number inbetween as in 1 to 5 ?

Comment: It looks like homework, so I think that's the reason.

Comment: yes, so it performs the same routine 5 times. But really look at the Excel formula in my answer because that's way simpler and faster.

Comment: Im being examined on loops so please nevermind the excel formula i need to get a basic understanding of this, I know your way is faster!

I dont quite get the amount = amount  * (1 +rate)...

Comment: Also why its amount - investment in the end? isnt amount = investment?

Comment: Actually I think you can figure that out yourself, since these are fairly simple questions. I'm not here to make your homework for you.

Comment: Well if I didnt try I wouldnt be here, thanks for the help anyway. Have a good one

Comment: If this was a homework assignment (probable), it's likely that the OP didn't actually write the *answer* to it given the question.

Answer (score 0):

What the i and amount means is that it is variables that changes after each time the loop is executed.

In your case years total is 5, which means the loop will run for a max of 5 times.
Your starting amount is 1000. After 1 year of interest with 5% (1st loop) equals 1050. Second time (the i is now equal to 2 out of 5) the starting amount is now 1050 and now it calculates 5% of the 1050, and so on all the way to 5 times amounting to your total of €276 of interest.

Hope this brings some clarity :)